# What is a good brand for parmesan to buy in Rome?

Tags: cheese, italian-cuisine, parmesan

I'm soon going to Rome for vacation and want to bring back some parmigiano reggiano cheese. Could anyone suggest a good brand and a good place to buy this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site @Cody. Unfortunately this question is off topic as you are asking for an opinion on which brands people like, and where a good place to shop is. Whatever you buy, remember to triple bag it when you bring it back as it will stink up your luggage like nobody's business.

Comment: It's ITALY !!!  and every single wheel is regulated by the Consorzio di Parmigiano-Reggiano. Go into any shop, don't worry about brand, in the sense that it's all parmigiano reggiano: they'll tell you the farm that produced it and the age. Are you returning to the US (just a guess): if you are, for Customs, make sure that it is properly packaged/labeled (and that you declare it). Cheese producers and grocers in Italy, even small operations, typically have a vacuum-packing machine, but make sure that they include a label with the name of the farm, its location and the type of cheese.

Comment: @Dorothy: Uhuh. Their streets are paved with gold, there's a unicorn around every corner, everyone is obeying all the rules, in short, it's  [Cockaigne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockaigne). Did I mention the unicorns?

Comment: @Dorothy: I'm happy you found your corner of the world :) But "It's ITALY !!!" just doesn't cut it, no matter how many exclamation marks you put after it ;)

Comment: @Dorothy: I never forgo a chance to be a gentleman. The pass is yours :)

Comment: @Dorothy not a prob, however what has the unicorn got to do with it?